# Can you make Google's reCAPTCHAs default to the sound version?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, captcha

Can you make Google's reCAPTCHAs default to the sound version? I am using Chrome and Firefox and I'm tired of having to manually select sound every time.

Comment: @Destroy666 Missed the notification. Will try tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: @Destroy666 One follow-up-question - would it be possible to automate downloading of the audio file? I would like to play it using VLC or something (so I can change the speed and apply filters etc). Thank you.

Comment: It would I think, but that's a topic for a different question, which I could take a look at tomorrow.

Comment: @Destroy666 That would be awesome. Just created a question for that, here https://superuser.com/questions/1800618/can-you-automate-download-of-the-audio-file-of-google-captchas . Have installed your script now, waiting for the first captcha to appear.

Comment: Did the script here work for your use case? Still not sure and can't continue if you don't state as the 2nd problem would have a similar solution.

Comment: @Destroy666 Haven't bumped into a captcha yet :-(

Comment: @Destroy666 Yes it worked! Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with a userscript. Example:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Autoplay Google reCAPTCHA v2
// @description  Attempts to autoplay audio version of Google reCAPTCHA v2.
// @namespace    https://github.com/Destroy666x
// @author       Destroy666
// @version      1.0
// @supportURL   https://github.com/Destroy666x/greasemonkey-script-collection
// @homepage     https://patreon.com/Designeous
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(async function() {
  'use strict';
  const { default: monitoring } = await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monitoring/dist/monitoring-latest.min.mjs');

  // Monitor with iframe support
  const monitor = monitoring(document.body, { iframes: true });
  const imagePopupSelector = '#rc-imageselect';
  const audioButtonSelector = '#recaptcha-audio-button';
  const playButtonSelector = '.rc-button-default';

  // We need to monitor the popup as it's buggy for the button (or some children in general)
  monitor.appeared(
    imagePopupSelector,
    el => {
        el.querySelector(audioButtonSelector).click();
    }
  );

  // Also monitor the popup with the play button to press it, here it works directly
  monitor.appeared(
    playButtonSelector,
    el => {
        el.click();
    }
  );
})();
```

Paste this as e.g. new [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) script and then make sure it's enabled.

Note that using a script like that might influence reCaptcha's bot score and you might get more challenges for seeming too automatic.

Comment: It works, thank you.

Comment: Did you see my follow-up question here https://superuser.com/questions/1800618/can-you-automate-download-of-the-audio-file-of-google-captchas ?