# Can you automate download of the audio file of Google Captchas?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, captcha

As a follow-up to this question [Can you make Google's reCAPTCHAs default to the sound version?](https://superuser.com/questions/1796076/can-you-make-googles-recaptchas-default-to-the-sound-version) - can you automate the download of the audio version of Google's captchas? The purpose is to play them in an external player so you can change playback speed, apply filters etc.

Comment: Yes that is possible. So, you are turning captchas into audio and then you use Whisper to translate 'em to text? I am not so sure we should help people break reCaptcha (spam is fucking annoying).

Comment: It doesn't have to be for malicious purposes, I'm personally not going to assume the intent of this or future users. As for breaking, this way would be extremely inefficient for spam bots and alike anyways, much easier and quicker ways to solve them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a userscript can be used for this, too:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Download Audio Google reCAPTCHA v2
// @description  Attempts to download audio version of Google reCAPTCHA v2.
// @namespace    https://github.com/Destroy666x
// @author       Destroy666
// @version      1.0
// @supportURL   https://github.com/Destroy666x/greasemonkey-script-collection
// @homepage     https://patreon.com/Designeous
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(async function() {
  'use strict';
  const { default: monitoring } = await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monitoring/dist/monitoring-latest.min.mjs');

  // Monitor with iframe support
  const monitor = monitoring(document.body, { iframes: true });
  const imagePopupSelector = '#rc-imageselect';
  const audioButtonSelector = '#recaptcha-audio-button';
  const downloadButtonSelector = '.rc-audiochallenge-tdownload-link';

  // We need to monitor the popup as it's buggy for the button (or some children in general)
  monitor.appeared(
    imagePopupSelector,
    el => {
        el.querySelector(audioButtonSelector).click();
    }
  );

  // Also monitor the popup with the play button to press it, here it works directly
  monitor.appeared(
    downloadButtonSelector,
    el => {
        el.click();
    }
  );
})();
```

It's quite similar to the one from here: https://superuser.com/a/1796175/1145698

Also the same note applies - using automation can result in more captchas appearing for you, up to you to decide if you want to use it.